# Connect to an Oracle 8.0 database using a 10g client

Tags: oracle, oracleclient

I recently upgraded my oracle client to 10g (10.2.0.1.0).

Now when I try to connect to a legacy 8.0 database, I get

```
ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported.
```

Is there any workaround for this problem, or do I have to install two clients on my local machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, you can connect to an Oracle 8i database with the 10g client, but the 8i Database requires the 8.1.7.3 patchset, which you can get from [Oracle's Metalink support site](http://metalink.oracle.com/) (requires login).

Here's an [Oracle forum post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=241380) with the details.

---

If updating your Oracle Database isn't an option, then you can have 2 different clients installed (in different "Oracle Homes" (or directories), and use the `selecthome.bat` file to switch between your installed clients.

For example, before connecting to 8i, you'd run:

`C:\Oracle\Client1_8i\bin\selecthome.bat`

or this to use your Oracle 10g client:

`C:\Oracle\Client2_10g\bin\selecthome.bat`

Comment: You're right, but I deinstalled the old (9i) client that I was using.  So now I only have one oracle home.

Comment: Updated: I found an oracle forum post detailing a patchset - is patching your 8i Database an option?

Comment: Not really, and I'm running 8.0 anyway... But your answer seems right for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to connect a C# code to an Oracle 7 (I know you it's 8...)... the only way I get it was to get the CD to install the Oracle Server and to go in the "Optional Configuration Component" and to use the Oracle73 Ver2.5.

I think you should go check the CD of the Oracle 8 Server and check if an ODBC is still available.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to connect an Oracle 8.1.7 and higher is through Instant Client. Download Instant client 10.2 from oracle site, copy all files in the same folder where .NET  assemblies resides and use classes located in System.Data.OracleClient. This work for me in .NET 4 project and oracle DB 8.1.7 server.

Comment: The question asks about Oracle 8.0, so I don't see how this answer is helpful.